# Can we engineer detergent micelles to pick up Microplastics?

Tags: chemical-engineering

I'd like to know if I could get micelles to pick up microplastics in water. I read that microplastics are sometimes charged, so can we make the lyophobic end to pick up microplastics, so that they can then be collected on the water surface and be easily disposed? This is the idea I'm planning to pitch this for a science fair, is this actually feasible? I read that detergent micelles work well even in hard water, so can we use such detergent micelles to pick up microplastics?

Thanks!

Comment: I doubt they'll be charged once they're wet. Water is conductive when there are salts in it.

Comment: Even if they aren't charged, can we still use micelles to pick Microplastics up?